# Decipher these files into Blender friendly notation

Tags: texturing

Greetings Blenderites,

I bought this texture pack from an artist.  You can see the file naming conventions aren't perfect for Blender (at least as I understand it).

I'm used to seeing:

name_COLOR

name_NORM

name_AO

name_BUMP, etc.

Can you help me figure out which of these mountain texture files should be renamed?

[image: mountains]

Here's my initial attempt at making sense of it...
[image]

Not sure if the _COLOR file is correct.  Or if I even need a _COLOR file??

Comment: Hi :). AO, Roughness, Normal, Height are clearly marked. The other BW maps are probably to color/populate the geometry using different parameters. Why not just ask the artist? ;)

Comment: Those look like maps used by GIS software for doing shaded relief rendering

Comment: @Jachym, I have.  He's in Iran.  He actually did get back to me and will reply again later.  Just figured I'd get a jump on it from the community.  Shouldn't there be a _COLOR file?